# .htaccess How to match only the first appearance of index.php in the URL?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following question. Let's say I have link like

`http://localhost/test/index.php/admin`

I have the following htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) $1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

What it does is simply remove index.php from the URL. However, when I enter url like this:

`http://localhost/test/abc/blabla/index.php`

It goes on an infinite loop. What I want is to do nothing when another index.php is met in the URL. How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$` is going to match **EVERYTHING** in the url. so when the redirect occurs to index.php/index.php, you'll match that, redirect to index.php/index.php/index.php etc... You need to exclude `^index.php`

Comment: @MarcB Can you show me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)r(&|$)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php(?:/(.*))?$ $1$2?r [R=302,NE,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php/).+)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: This code won't work for me. It removes both index.php's, so that
`http://localhost/test/index.php/admin/index.php` OR
`http://localhost/test/admin/index.php`
both return
`http://localhost/test/admin/`

I just want the first index.php removed, others (if any met) should remain.

Comment: Oh ok that will be tricky. See updated code now. It will add a small query parameter `r` to prevent further redirects.

Comment: Looks good, but is there another way, without `r`? All I want is the second, third, etc.. `index.php` to be part of the URL.

Comment: NO because after a redirect happens Apache receives a totall new request and it has no knowledge that it has already removed `index.php` previously. This additional parameter `r` is to give that knowledge only. Only other way I can think of is by using cookies and even that will be clumsy too.

Comment: If it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.